# Getting Hour and minute in from DATEDIFF in decmial format, SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL table I have 3 coulmns:

```
StartDateTime (DATETIME),
EndDateTime   (DATETIME),
TimeWorked    (DECIMAL(9,2))
```

I am trying to fill the TimeWorked column with the total hours and minutes between the start and end time. If I use

`DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartDateTime, EndDateTime)`

I get the hours rounded down, so I thought I would use

`DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) / 60`

but on a time of 90 minutes I am given 1.00 hours. I did some searching and found most places suggest converting the number so I tried converting just the result of the `DATEDIFF` and the entire math equation like

```
CONVERT(decimal(9,2),(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartDateTime, EndDateTime)) / 60);
CONVERT(decimal(9,2),(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) / 60));
```

but the results are still being rounded down to the nearest hour. The times I am using to test are:

```
StartDateTime
2014-10-13 17:30:00.000

EndDateTime
2014-10-13 19:00:00.000
```

What is the best way to get the number or hours and minutes in a decimal format (i.e. 1.5 would be the correct result for this time)? If it makes any difference this is being in the `SET` part of an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: I am hoping to get 1.5, I want the hours in decimal format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) / 60.0` to avoid integer division and get the result you want.

This works because `60.0` is interpreted as a literal of the `decimal` rather than `integer` type.

The problem with your approach here

```
 CONVERT(decimal(9,2),(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) / 60));
```

Is that the integer division already occurs before the cast. So you are just converting the integer `1` to a `decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
  , @EndDate DATETIME

SELECT  @StartDate = '2014-10-13 17:30:00.000'
SELECT  @EndDate = '2014-10-13 19:00:00.000'
```

Then SELECT as below:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate) / 60.0
```

OR

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2), DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate) / 60.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use this idea as well:

```
declare @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime

select @StartDate = '2014-10-13 17:30:00.000'
select @EndDate =   '2014-10-13 19:00:00.000'

select convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)/3600) + ':' 
     + convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)%3600/60) + ':'
     + convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)%60)) as [hh:mm:ss]
,(convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)/3600)) as H
,(convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)%3600/60) /60.) as M
,(convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)%60)) /60.) as S
,(convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)/3600)) 
+(convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)%3600/60) /60.)
+(convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)%60)) /60.) as DT_Diff
```

Results:

```
hh:mm:ss    H   M           S           DT_Diff
1:30:0      1   0.500000    0.000000    1.500000
```